# Linq recursive parent child

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I have data from database like that :

```
id | description              | parent_id
-----------------------------------------
1  | Record 1                 | null
2  | Record 2                 | 1
3  | Record 3                 | null
4  | Record 4                 | 2
5  | Record 5                 | 3
```

I want to process using Linq, and it should be result like this :

```
Record 1
- Record 2
  - Record 4
Record 3
- Record 5
```

I got solution : [Recursive LINQ query: select item and all children with subchildren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262391/recursive-linq-query-select-item-and-all-children-with-subchildren)

but unfortunately the result only has two level, because i want the result in multi level > 2 levels (like a tree).

Any other best solution ? or how to modification that solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: `whatever`? It was a totally legit question since you can use LINQ on your database and a list.

Comment: Not _whatever_. A recursive solution for linq would not work for linq-to-sql or linq-to-entities.

Comment: Linq does not have this support. You will need to write a recursive function call to do so. Link will support up to as many layers as you wish to define

Comment: oh okay, sorry. i mean linq to objects

Comment: @Nico yes it need to write a recursive function. as mentioned above, i got solution, but the results only has two level, i need the results have multiple level

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For linq-to-objects you can define your own extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` that recursively gets all children.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectRecursive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
    {
        foreach (var parent in source)
        {
            yield return parent;

            var children = selector(parent);
            foreach (var child in SelectRecursive(children, selector))
                yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var lookup = col.ToLookup(x => x.Parent_Id);
var res = lookup[null].SelectRecursive(x => lookup[x.Id]).ToList();
```

Comment: some way to add separators to child nodes?

Comment: @Pablogrind Not sure what you mean by "separators"?

Comment: @Magnus hi, like Record 1
- Record 2
 -- Record 4 ,  add "-" in text column to display child in select