# Speeding up dynamic menus creation recursively

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have the following menu structures

```
A
-B
-C
D
-E
--F
```

And so on. `A` has childs `B, C`, `D` has childs `E`, and `E` has childs `F`

I created a way to render my menus recursively.
But for some reason (that i dont know) its getting really slow

```
A, D = parent nodes, with parent = null
```

Here is my procedure

`1.` get all parent nodes with parent = null, in this case A and D.

`2.` For each of them check whether they have a child or not.

`2.1` If they have a child, get the childs and iterate over them in `1`

`2.2` If they dont have a child, simply print them, and go to next item.

Can I apply some kind of memoization to this?

Here is the C# code

`allMenus` is all the possible menus.

```
@helper renderTree(IEnumerable<Menu> menus, IEnumerable<Menu> allMenus)
        {
            foreach (var item in menus)
            {
                var result = item.MenuName;

                //if has childs
                if (allMenus.Where(m => m.ParentID == item.MenuID).Any())
                {
                    <li class="treeview">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="@item.IconName"></i>
                            <span>
                                @{
                                    @Html.Raw(result);

                                }
                            </span>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                @{
                                    // get the childs
                                    var childs = allMenus.Where(m => m.ParentID == item.MenuID); 
                                    @renderTree(childs, allMenus);
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action(@item.ActionName, @item.ControllerName, new { area = @item.AreaName }, null)">
                            <i class="@item.IconName"></i>
                            <span>@Html.Raw(result)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: One obvious optimization is that you do the call same `.Where(...)` twice. `if (allMenus.Where(m => m.ParentID == item.MenuID).Any())` colud be transformed into `var childs = allMenus.Where(m => m.ParentID == item.MenuID); if(childs.Any()) ...` Then you can reuse the result

Comment: Agree with @mortb. The other optimizations can be do create parent-child hierarchy and iterate over it to render element. See this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608665/linq-recursive-parent-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608665/linq-recursive-parent-child)

Comment: Thanks. @mortb, that small tweak actually helped.

Comment: Also, your code does not show how the menuItems are loaded. If the IEnumerable is not materialized and it is made from a database query (or some file operation) every call to `.Where(...)` will do the enumeration and lead to databse query /  file operation.  See for example here: http://www.ytechie.com/2009/06/delayed-execution-vs-tolist-in-linq-database-queries/

Comment: good point @mortb. I materialized using `.toList()` this decreased my code speed by like 80-90%. Thank you. That's what was missing

Comment: Glad to help :) When code executes so slowly that it is a problem, most of the time there are calls to some resource (database, internet, files etc) that are problematic