# Recursive LINQ select based on SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, recursion

I was wondering if there is a way to convert a SQL syntaxt to LINQ to Entities

Example:

```
var test = employeeeTable.Where(x => x.FatherId == -1).Select(i => new Employee
        {
            Id = i.Id;
            FatherId = i.FatherId;
        }).
```

I have built this query on SQL, but since I am using a recursive way in SQL I don't know how to handle that in LINQ

```
WITH tempTable (Id, FatherId, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
SELECT e.Id, e.FatherId, 1 AS Level
FROM dbo.Employees AS e
WHERE FatherId = -1

UNION ALL

-- Recursive member definition
SELECT e.Id, e.FatherId, Level + 1
FROM dbo.Employees AS e
INNER JOIN tempTable AS d ON e.FatherId = d.Id
)
```

Comment: Any SQL you would generate from a LINQ query would be ugly as hell. Your best bet would be to create a View or Stored Procedure and just call that.

Comment: I am trying to convert SQL to LINQ.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive LINQ query: select item and all children with subchildren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262391/recursive-linq-query-select-item-and-all-children-with-subchildren)

Comment: @GilQuintero Correct, but then Entity Framework converts your LINQ to SQL. It isn't able to create as efficient queries as you are manually. When you get into recursion, I would imagine that the problem of inefficiency would only grow exponentially.