# EF self referencing table determine cycles

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a self referencing table and I am using entity framework to define it.

```
public class Table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Table Parent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Parent))]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Table> Children { get; set; } = new List<Table>();
}
```

Using only EF can I determine when I add a new relationship that there is a cycle. For example with the data:

- Item 1

  - Item 2

    - Item 3
  - Item 4
  - Item 5

when I try to add Item 1 to Item 3 I should determine that a cycle would be created.

Answer (score 0):

By "only EF" I assume you mean : by a single Linq query

Then AFAIK, this i not possible.

You should read: [Recursive LINQ query: select item and all children with subchildren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262391/recursive-linq-query-select-item-and-all-children-with-subchildren/21262626)

Consider the following "not only EF" code:

```
public AddChildren(Table t) {
    var parent = this;
    while ( parent != null ) {
        if ( parent.Id == t.Id )
            throw new Exception("cycle");
        parent = parent.Parent;
    }
    Children.Add(t);
}
```

WARNING: possible infinite loop in case of existing loop.

May be you should also:

- check for duplicate child
- consider using intervallaire tree representation: https://sqlpro.developpez.com/cours/arborescence/ (sorry I can't find english paper). Whith this representation an "EF only" solution exists.